# img desaturate in all browsers - problem

Tags: jquery, css

I used to use the **pixastic** (http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/) on mouse over to desaturate images.
now i need the image to be desaturated onload and to get color on mouse over

so i have tried with modifing the pixastic code and it worked but in Chrome the image of the grayscale one was ignored the width and hiehgt (the images uploaded can be big so i use inline height to resize)

then i have tried **Image Desaturate jQuery plugin** (http://dev.artutkin.ru/desaturate/)
but the same thing happend to photo that is big...

what can be done about that?

Answer (score 0):

i used this tutorial http://webdesignerwall.com/demo/html5-grayscale/ and works fine on chrome, ie9, firefox dont tested another ones.